TypeScript generic type: Makes all object's fields optional recursively, unless the field's type is array
I've been trying to create a generic TypeScript type, that makes all fields of an object optional, unless they are an Array. Including the nested fields inside objects, or fields in objects that are elements of arrays.
For the TestType, the desired type SpecialPartial should yield a type where all the fields are optional, except for field2 and field4 which are arrays.
type TestType = { field1: string; field2: Array<string>; field3: { field4: Array<{ field5: string }> } }

const arr: SpecialPartial<TestType>[] = []
arr.push({ field2: [], field3: { field4: [{}] } }) // Should not cause errors
arr.push({}) // Should cause an error due to lack of field2-array

I've tried a couple of things, such as:
type SpecialPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer U>
    ? Array<SpecialPartial<U>>
    : T[P] | undefined
}

However, this makes the root-level array-fields optional too, but it doesnt make all the fields inside objects-in-arrays optional.
The difficulty is that optional is not the same thing as union with undefined. I want optional, so that I don't have to input a hundred fields as explicitly undefined: { field1: undefined } etc.

I asked a similar question here which might help. It's not a recursive type like you need though, so it's not a duplicate. Also i was trying to make only arrays optional, while you're trying to make everything but.

@NicholasTower thanks, that's looks like the right direction, though I still can't wrap my head around it yet

Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jclaz It looks like exactly what I want!

Please triple check... these deeply nested types always have bizarre edge cases, and I don't want to spend 45 minutes writing up an explanation for something that turns out not to work for you.  Let me know.

@jcalz Well, I tried all the test cases I could think of, and then I stuck it in my real code and it seems to do exactly what I want. Would take me some days to test it in all the code but I'm pretty confident already. I switched the any's to unknown's though due to linter, you think that's ok? In any case, thanks a lot.

Yes, unknown[] is fine for any[].  I'll write up my answer targeting the example here... if several days from now you find a problem, you could open a new question for it... does that sound reasonable?

Unfortunately you can't conditionally set or unset the optionality mapping modifier; there's a longstanding open issue for it at microsoft/TypeScript#32562.  For now, the closest you can get is to divide up the properties into the ones to make optional and the ones to leave alone, and then intersect the result together.
With that in mind, here's a possible implementation of SpecialPartial<T>:
type SpecialPartial<T> = T extends object ? (
  T extends readonly any[] ? { [I in keyof T]: SpecialPartial<T[I]> } :
  (
    { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends readonly any[] ? K : never]: SpecialPartial<T[K]> } &
    { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends readonly any[] ? never : K]?: SpecialPartial<T[K]> }
  ) extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never
) : T

First we check if T is an object type as opposed to a primitive. We don't want to modify primitives, so we have something that looks like T extends object ? ( ⋯ ) : T.
Then we check if T is an array type. If so, we really don't want to try to split its properties into optional and required ones, because we just want an array in to become an array out. And that's what a regular old mapped type does, so that part looks like T extends readonly any[] ? {[I in keyof T]: SpecialPartial<T[I]> } : ⋯.  So Array<X> becomes Array<SpecialPartial<X>>.
Finally comes the core of the implementation, where T is a non-array object.  Here we split into two mapped types that are intersected together. I use the property-filtering functionality in key-remapping via as. For each property key K, we retain the key if and only if the property T[K] is (or alternately, is not) an array type.  For all array properties, we just map as-is, without changing the mapping modifier.  We just apply SpecialPartial<T[K]> to the property type.  For all non-array properties, we map with the optional ? mapping modifier. And apply SpecialPartial<T[K]> also. So that part looks like { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends readonly any[] ? K : never]: SpecialPartial<T[K]> } & { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends readonly any[] ? never : K]?: SpecialPartial<T[K]> }.
That could be it, but here I also use a trick to collapse the intersection to a single object type (e.g., {a: 0} & {b?: 1} to {a: 0; b?: 1}), by using conditional type inference to copy the type into a new type parameter U, and then performing an identity mapped type over it.
Okay, let's test it out:
type TestType = {
  field1: string;
  field2: Array<string>;
  field3: {
    field4: Array<{ field5: string }>
  }
}

type Z = SpecialPartial<TestType>
/* type Z = {
    field2: Array<string>;
    field1?: string | undefined;
    field3?: {
        field4: {
            field5?: string | undefined;
        }[];
    } | undefined;
} */

Looks like what you want. We can make sure your test cases work as desired:
const arr: SpecialPartial<TestType>[] = []
arr.push({ field2: [], field3: { field4: [{}] } }) // okay
arr.push({}) // error! Property 'field2' is missing

Yep, that's what you wanted.
Playground link to code
